# Is there a way to differentiate between paid and free apps in iTunes purchase history?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

I want to know what apps I've paid money for, as opposed to free apps that were downloaded.

I need to know this because I gave my little brother my old 3GS to use as an iPod which remains attached to my iTunes account because he doesn't have a credit card or an income in order set up an account. I notice that he downloads a lot of apps, games in particular, and I'm worried because I've tried a few that seem like they could easily charge for. I often download apps that I pay for, so often that I wouldn't know if he was buying things without my knowledge.

Every now and then I notice a charge from iTunes that I don't remember making, so I need to know what I've paid for. Is there a way to show what apps I've actually spent money on?

Comment: I think it is worth noting that there is NO reason to give someone else access to your iTunes account, ESPECIALLY one with purchasing power linked to your finances. All you need in order to download free apps is an Apple ID linked to an email address; no credit card is required!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to keeping your email receipts, you can also view your entire purchase history by viewing your account in iTunes. If you're signed in, click your account name in the top right, and choose the "View Account" option. On the following screen, the third section down shows "Purchase History", with a link on the right to see all your orders. You can see each order, listed chronologically, and jump to specific months and get more detail about a specific order.

Comment: Great answer! I'm glad to see this feature was added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save and process your email receipts to know what you paid. (or somehow scrape the history from within iTunes) - it's simply not an option you can sort currently.

Since prices change on the store, some other solution that doesn't involve your paid balance being shown isn't a tool that has been provided.

Many have asked for this since it makes so much sense for a variety of use cases -- in addition to the situation you find yourself in. Unless you have the ear of someone that works in the iTunes store, http://apple.com/feedback is the best way to agitate for change.